# Cannot Load Java Resources in Spark from Scala

Tags: java, scala

I have a `java` project containing a class `MyFileLoader` (among others) that successfully loads a file from resources using:

```
public static List<String> loadFile() {
    Path path = System.class.getResource("/my/path/model.bin").getFile().toPath();
    return Files.readAllLines(path, UTF_8);
}
```

and then does some processing.

After adding this project/jar as a dependency in `scala`, I tried to access  `MyFileLoader.loadFile`. Unfortunately, this gives a `java.lang.NullPointerException`, as the resource isn't found.

To debug, I ran this command in `spark-shell`, showing that this resource indeed exists:

```
scala> getClass.getResource("/my/path/model.bin").getFile
res32: String =  file:/some-local-path/my-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/my/path/model.bin
```

I then tried:

```
scala> Files.readAllLines(new File(getClass.getResource("/my/path/model.bin").getPath).toPath)
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: file:/some-local-path/my-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/my/path/model.bin
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:384)
at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:152)
at java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedReader(Files.java:2784)
at java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(Files.java:3202)
at java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(Files.java:3242)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:20)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:25)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:27)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:29)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:31)
at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:33)
at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:35)
at $iwC.<init>(<console>:37)
at <init>(<console>:39)
at .<init>(<console>:43)
at .<clinit>(<console>)
at .<init>(<console>:7)
at .<clinit>(<console>)
at $print(<console>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1338)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:856)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:901)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:813)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:656)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:664)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:669)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:996)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:944)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:944)
at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:944)
at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1058)
at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:569)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:166)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:189)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:110)
at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Why aren't I able to load the resource these ways?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your file is now packaged inside of jar you will need to use `Class.getResourceAsStream()`. It seems you are trying to read the URL as a regular file which isn't supported (it likely worked before since it wasn't packaged inside of the jar and was able to be loaded as a regular file).